# Making entered text appear on the screen without knowing the positions

Tags: javascript, html

How can I have the user enter some text (in a text area, for example), and have it appear on the screen. If the user enters another message, the program should display that underneath the first message, and so on. So far, the user can enter a message and it replaces an empty p element that is already defined. This works when the user enters a single message, but when you enter multiple times, the new text replaces the old text in the p element. Below is what I've tried so far.

```js
function displayText(element, change_to) {
  document.getElementById(element).textContent =
    document.getElementById(change_to).value;
  document.getElementById(change_to).value = "";
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: skyblue;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#enterMsg {
    margin-top: 34%;
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: darkorange;
    background-color: #d796ff;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.enterText {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: darkorange;
    background-color: #d796ff;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#sendButton {
    margin-left: 96%;
}

#msg {
    margin-left: 80%;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #b19cd9;
    background-color: #b4ff94;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: darkorange;
}

.extraSpace {
    padding: 5px;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: darkorange;
}

div.centered {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.confirmButton {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p id="msg" class="extraSpace"></p>
<textarea id="enterMsg" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
<button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function displayText(element, change_to) {
  document.getElementById(element).textContent += 
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^~~~~~~~~~
    document.getElementById(change_to).value;
  document.getElementById(change_to).value = "";
}
```

```html
<p id="msg" class="extraSpace"></p>
<textarea id="enterMsg" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
<button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>
```

Or better yet:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("sendButton");
button.addEventListener("click", displayText);

function displayText() {
  const display = document.getElementById("msg");
  const textArea = document.getElementById("enterMsg");

  display.append(
    textArea.value,
    document.createElement("br")
  );

  textArea.value = "";
}
```

```html
<p id="msg" class="extraSpace"></p>
<textarea id="enterMsg" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
<button id="sendButton">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try appending HTML to the innerHTML of the element.

```js
function displayText(element, change_to) {
  document.getElementById(element).innerHTML +=
    document.getElementById(change_to).value + "<br/>";
  document.getElementById(change_to).value = "";
}
```

```html
<p id="msg" class="extraSpace"></p>
<textarea id="enterMsg" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
<button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>
```

Or try appending another element to a container (which I recommend):

```js
function displayText(element, change_to) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerText = document.getElementById(change_to).value;
  document.getElementById(element).appendChild(p);
  document.getElementById(change_to).value = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="msg">
</div>
<textarea id="enterMsg" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
<button id="sendButton" onclick="displayText('msg', 'enterMsg')">Send</button>
```

Comment: Ohh, that's a smart way to deal with this.

Comment: @DavidBagel Does my answer answer your question?

Comment: I like your `appendChild()` solution! But you should know: `Element.innerText` is much slower than the preferred `Element.textContent`

Comment: @Spectric - Yes.

Comment: @JacobLockwood Thanks. However, `innerHTML` is required to force a newline.

Comment: @Spectric you could also append a <br /> element (like in my solution)

Comment: @JacobLockwood I did append a `br` element.

Comment: Oh, I meant like `appendChild(document.createElement("br"))`

Comment: @JacobLockwood I don't need to do that.

Comment: @Spectric Appending user-generated text [using `innerHTML` comes with some risk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations). As this messaging seems to be an online-chat "mock-up", it is fine, but if it was truly online, it should **not** be used.

Comment: @OskarGrosser Agreed. That's why I recommended appending a `<p>` element and setting the innerText to the user input.

Answer (score 1):

## How to append text

### Our goal

We want to append a user's text-message to a container, with each message seperated (means, on a new line).

Thinking about HTML and CSS, the seperation can be achieved in multiple ways (most likely a ton more ways, too!):

- HTML

  - Using `\n` (line-breaks)
  - Using `<br>` (line-breaks)
  - Using seperate elements for each message
- CSS

  - Using e.g. `white-space: pre-wrap`

We will discuss some ways to append the text and how to seperate them.

### Why not to use `innerHTML`

Appending text may be thought of as being as simple as adding to [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). This might not only break some JavaScript, [**it even is dangerous!**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations)

Appending user-generated text to `innerHTML` should be discouraged, because—well—it allows for some simple "hacks":
Say, you enable this messaging-feature to be online. Then, one could type something as simple as this:

```
<div onmouseover="alert('This may have been a harmful script!');">&nbsp;</div>
```

Try it out!

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  document.body.innerHTML += input.value + '<br>'; 
  /* `<body>`'s HTML is changed and needs to be re-evaluated;
   * all elements are re-generated, which means, there actually is
   * a new button, which doesn't have the previous listener.
   * Try sending another message!
   */
  input.value = '';
});
```

```html
<input>
<button>Send</button>
```

The script might then run on everyone's browser, and gather harmful information.

How to avoid this, you ask? Use e.g. `Element.append()` or `textContent`. Really, it's that simple!

### Using `Element.append()`

We can also use [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to append [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)s, of which [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) is one of.

This means, we can either append single `Text`-Nodes, or individual `Element`s containing the text. When using `append()` for this purpose, I'd recommend individual elements.

Reason is, when appending text-nodes, you are limiting your styling to one element. You cannot even alternate the messages' horizontal alignment (which is by now basically a must-have for foreign and own messages).

Here is an interactive example with styling:

```js
addFormListener('foreign');
addFormListener('own');

function addFormListener(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    submitMessage(evt.target[0].value, id);
    evt.target[0].value = '';
  });
}

function submitMessage(message, className) {
  const msgElement = document.createElement('p');
  msgElement.classList.add(className);
  msgElement.textContent = message;
  document.querySelector('output').append(msgElement);
}
```

```css
html {height: 100%}
body {margin: 0;min-height: 100%}
div {
  padding: .5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  place-items: center;
}
label {display: block}
output {
  min-height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

output p {
  margin: .1rem;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  min-width: 16ex;
  max-width: 80%;
  width: fit-content;
  line-break: anywhere;
}
output .foreign {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background: #83ce83;
}
output .own {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: #6bb9fb;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="foreign">
    <label for="foreign-input">Foreign input:</label>
    <input id="foreign-input">
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
  <form id="own">
    <label for="own-input">Own input:</label>
    <input id="own-input">
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
<output></output>
```

But using `Text` is very similar to using `textContent`, which brings us to the next section.

### Using `textContent`/`innerText`

Instead of using `innerHTML`, use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or (preferably) [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). (You already do? Awesome!)

These two aren't vulnerable in the way `innerHTML` is, which makes them great candidates to be used.

Quick heads-up on their differences ([extract from MDN *Node.textContent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)):

> - `textContent` gets the content of *all* elements, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements. In contrast, `innerText` only shows “human-readable” elements.
> - `textContent` returns every element in the node. In contrast, `innerText` is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.
>
>   - Moreover, since `innerText` takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of `innerText` triggers a [reflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Reflow) to ensure up-to-date computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.)
> - Unlike `textContent`, altering `innerText` in Internet Explorer (version 11 and below) removes child nodes from the element and *permanently destroys* all descendant text nodes. It is impossible to insert the nodes again into any other element or into the same element after doing so.

Using (only) these means we cannot add `<br>` to the HTML. Instead, we need to use `\n`.

*"But my browser doesn't show the line-break!"*, you might say. Yeah, the default CSS of most elements specifies `white-space: normal`, which ignores line-breaks in the code.

Instead, we want `white-space: pre-wrap`. This both shows our manually placed line-breaks and adds a line-break when the text would have overflown the content-box. The best of both worlds!

Here an example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  
  document.querySelector('output').textContent += input.value + '\n';
  input.value = '';
});
```

```css
output {white-space: pre-wrap}
```

```html
<input>
<button>Send</button>
<div>
  <output></output>
</div>
```

Technically, these approaches suffice to achieve what we wanted. There is just one problem with them.

### Accessibility

Now, imagine you have to use literally *any* accessibility device/software. You would depend on the browser correctly interpreting and outputting the website's content.

Here is my opinion:

> Poor accessibility means poor usability.

When developing websites, *always* think about making them accessible to people. This includes more than sighted people. This includes *all* people.

This means, using semantic HTML, labelling and grouping when necessary, and perhaps changing some element's so-called [ARIA-role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles).

#### Use semantical HTML

You have an input-field (`<textarea>`) and a `<button>` to submit your entered message.
Wait, submit? Sounds familiar to a `<form>`'s purpose! Not only that, we even need to group it. So using `<form>` sounds pretty logical.

*"But when submitting a form, we load another page!"*

Not if we disable that. It's as simple as calling `event.preventDefault()`.

What you might have also seen is code like this, where the listener is added in a `<script>`:

```html
<a href="#">Another "button"!</a> <!-- Or -->
<a href="javascript:;">Like a button!</a>
```

Never do this! This is misleading to assistive technology and should be purged!
If you really want a button to look like a link, use CSS! Same for the other way around.

And having multiple messages in one `<p>`-element? Well, are they one cohesive text? If not, split them up.

#### Labelling

You have used a `placeholder`-attribute, which seems good (visually), but doesn't replace an actual `<label>`. There is a list about [*why `placeholder` doesn't replace `<label>`* on W3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/low-vision-a11y-tf/wiki/Placeholder_Research) and more.

If you are so inclined to not (visually) show the label for whatever reason, you might want to read up on "screen-reader only"-CSS classes. In short, they make elements effectively invisible on your page, but they are still recognized by assistive technology.
Most implementations only require you to add one class to your element to hide it.

A quick search gave me this [implementation from a11yproject.com](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-11-how-to-hide-content/):

```css
.visually-hidden {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

#### Use ARIA-roles

If you ever want to re-purpose some element, or implement a custom one, then you probably (not always!) need to re-assign it another ARIA-role.

For example, a `<div>` is by default of `presentation` role, but if you were to add an `onclick`-listener, you should assign it the role of a `button`. This would be done like this: `aria-role="button"`

### Afterword

I'd recommend to not use inline JavaScript, as it de-centralizes your code. Instead, organize it so that all your JavaScript is in either a `<script>`-element or in one or more files. Same goes for CSS with its `<style>`-element.

Keeping all the above in mind when developing might seem like a daring task. But actually, it isn't that hard to remember all of it. Remembering them can be as easy as questioning yourself why you do what you do at all times, at least after once its done.

Comment: @JacobLockwood Personally I think it is good that your answer is accepted. It gives a very brief and concise answer to what was asked, especially to people who know programming. I just threw this answer in for some of the more curious people that might want to dig deeper into the "what-if".